# Login failed: 530 Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption

Tags: lftp

OS: OS X 10.9.3

lftp version:

```
LFTP | Version 4.5.1 | Copyright (c) 1996-2014 Alexander V. Lukyanov
```

After upgraded to lftp 4.5.1, I got this error when mput files to the same ftp.

Is there any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
lftp -e 'set ssl:verify-certificate false' -u username,password -p 1234 ftp.example.com
```

or add config in `~/.lftprc`

```
set ssl:verify-certificate false
```